# Flutter keyboard done button causes textfield content to dissapper

Tags: flutter, controller, keyboard, textfield

I Have a text field with an icon in a row I want to save the value in the text field tell I press on the icon to confirm the value not on the done button in the keyboard.

What occurs here that after clicking on done to close the keyboard the text in the text field disappear.

which results  when click on the icon gives null value.

**tried to solve this issue using behavior subject  to eliminate controller but doesnot work as the value in the text field remains there after click on the icon as there is no longer controller.

```
class ForumCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Forums choosentype;
  final ForumServices forumServices;
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore();
  final TextEditingController _textF = TextEditingController();

  ForumCard({Key key, @required this.choosentype, this.forumServices})
      : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    final user$ = authService.user.where((user) => user != null);
    final commentslist = List.from(choosentype.comments);
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 100,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
              stream: user$,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                final currentUser = snapshot.data;
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("nooooooooodata");
                }
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[

                    StreamBuilder<String>(
                        stream: forumServices.text,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Container();
                          }
                          final text = snapshot.data;
                          return choosentype.type == "question"
                              ? Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: 
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: TextField(
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintText: "Write a comment",
                                        ),
                                        onSubmitted: (String text) {
                                          forumServices.addtext(text);
// I am adding here in a stream was trying to eliminate controller but doesnot work as the value in the textfield remains there after click on the icon as there is no longer controller.
                                        },
                                        controller: _textF,
                                        onEditingComplete: null,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.comment),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        commentslist.add({
                                          "0": currentUser.uid,
                                          "1": currentUser.displayName,
                                          "2": _textF.text,
                                        });
                                        print(commentslist);
                                        Firestore.instance
                                            .collection('forums')
                                            .document(choosentype.uid)
                                            .updateData(
                                          {"comments": commentslist},
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your widget to be `StatefulWidget` to be able to preserve the state of the `TextFieldController`.